# Stacking the dataframes and ranking

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Can't quite find what I need in the questions, please correct me if I'm wrong. I have a number of dfs that are similar in shape and which may contain nans. Suppose a df that does not contain the nans looks like this:

```
np.random.seed(1)
mat = lambda: np.random.normal(size=10).reshape((5, 2))
df1 = pd.DataFrame(mat())
df2 = pd.DataFrame(mat())
df3 = pd.DataFrame(mat())
```

I want to somehow stack the `df1`, `df2` and `df3` on top of each other. And then rank each value across the `df1`, `df2`, `df3` (i.e. the stack levels).

So the individual dfs, in this case will look like:

`df1`

[image]

`df2`

[image]

`df3`

[image]

So in this case in the "`.iloc[0, 0]`" we have the values: 1.62, 1.46 and -1.1, so the ranked `df1` would have value `3`, `df2` would have value `2` and `df3` would have value `1`. And then this ranking is performed for each value across the dataframe levels. The general case will have about 16 dataframes stacked on top of each other and only 5 ranks, when there are nans, the df gets a rank of 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`GroupBy.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.rank.html):

```
df1.loc[0,1] = np.nan

df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], keys=('df1','df2','df3')).groupby(level=1).rank().fillna(0)
print (df)
         0    1
df1 0  3.0  0.0
    1  1.0  1.0
    2  1.0  1.0
    3  3.0  3.0
    4  3.0  1.0
df2 0  2.0  1.0
    1  2.0  2.0
    2  3.0  2.0
    3  1.0  2.0
    4  2.0  3.0
df3 0  1.0  2.0
    1  3.0  3.0
    2  2.0  3.0
    3  2.0  1.0
    4  1.0  2.0
```

Comment: beautiful, a one-liner. But why does df3 have 0 rank in `.iloc[0,0]`?

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal - I test NaN value, but for easier check was assigned to `df1.loc[0,1] = np.nan` - it return 0

Comment: how can this be extended to `x` ranks for `y` dataframes where `x` < `y`?

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal - hmmm, not sure if understand e.g. if need rank 2 for sample 3 df, what is expected output?

Comment: Suppose I only need 5 ranks but the number of dataframes is 16 or 21 etc. I.e. more than the number of ranks

Comment: Yes, but what should be first value in each dataframe from question if 2 rank?

Comment: think I'm complicating things. Can jut rank them `1` to however many dfs we have and them sum them all up to get a final df, and do the ranking on that final df.